# I want to create chrome extension that popups everytime when youtube play a video

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, youtube

Hello I want to create extension that popups when we play a video. When movie in full screen and we finish video and start new from related video . at that time extension popup  a alert
OK

..
.
. 
But I want full script. which will popup a messege every time youtube player state will change. I mean if we play a video than popup play, pause, finished etc. I m new in this.
also when we are in full screen.... thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a content script that catches player events:

```
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
    if(state === 0){
        alert('hey!');
    }
});
```

About detecting the full screen state, I don't think that youtube exposes that in it's API.

For more info look [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events):

Comment: A background script will not have access to the on-page player context.

Comment: My mistake, fixed to content script.

Comment: I'm doubtful that a content script will have access either. The content script and page loaded javascrpt execute in different contexts.